# Docker `CMD a b c` VS `CMD ["a", "b", "c"]`

Tags: docker, ipython, jupyter

When the command is specified as `CMD a b c` everything works as expected, while specifying the same command with `CMD ["a", "b", "c"]` - it gives unexpected result.
I'm trying to run Jupyter (ipython) inside docker. My `CMD` command is to start it. It seems that regardless of the way I specify it  - the Jupyter starts. But, only if I specify it as `CMD a b c` the jupyter actually works properly and it is possible to start a kernel. 
In this case "New Notebook" command works

```
    FROM debian:stable
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget bzip2
    RUN wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
        bash Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /anaconda2
    RUN /anaconda2/bin/conda install jupyter

    #CMD ["/anaconda2/bin/jupyter", "notebook", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--NotebookApp.token=''"]
    CMD /anaconda2/bin/jupyter notebook --port=8888 --no-browser --ip=0.0.0.0 --NotebookApp.token=''

    # docker build -t IMAGE_NAME .
    # docker run --rm -it -p 8888:8888 IMAGE_NAME
```

In this case "New Notebook" command does NOT work

```
    FROM debian:stable
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget bzip2
    RUN wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
        bash Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /anaconda2
    RUN /anaconda2/bin/conda install jupyter

    CMD ["/anaconda2/bin/jupyter", "notebook", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--NotebookApp.token=''"]
    #CMD /anaconda2/bin/jupyter notebook --port=8888 --no-browser --ip=0.0.0.0 --NotebookApp.token=''

    # docker build -t IMAGE_NAME .
    # docker run --rm -it -p 8888:8888 IMAGE_NAME
```

I'm really puzzled by this,  can't think of what could be the difference!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [*shell* form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) (`CMD a b c`) invokes the shell with a string that is parsed whereas the *exec* form (`CMD [a, b, c]`) launches the executable directly with the specified arguments.

As there is no shell parsing in the *exec* form (which, in this case, removed the empty quotes in the *shell* form), the last parameter should be, eg., `"--NotebookApp.token="`. This is given to the program as `--NotebookApp.token=`, without the two apostrophes.

---

From the manual:

> Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For example, CMD [ "echo", "$HOME" ] will not do variable substitution on $HOME. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or execute a shell directly, for example: CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME" ]. When using the exec form and executing a shell directly, as in the case for the shell form, it is the shell that is doing the environment variable expansion, not docker.

Comment: tbh, I was suspecting something like that. I've even tried `CMD ["bash", "a", "b", "c"]` - but apparently it should've been `CMD ["bash", "a b c"]`

Comment: @avloss `CMD ["bash", "-c", "a b c"]`

Comment: Thanks! well, actually `CMD ["bash", "-c", "a b c"]` didn't work! But `CMD ["sh", "-c", "a b c"]` did! So `jupyter` relies on some `env` vars it seems, and they aren't present in `bash`.